# How to implement IEnumerable in C# using generics

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable, ienumerator

My code has an iterator inner class which inherits from IEnumerator interface and Vector outer class which inherits from IEnumerable and IComparable interfaces.

```
public class Vector<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : IComparable<T>
```

I am unable to implement IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() and IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() methods properly. This is what I have so far

```
IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        //Iterator iterator = new Iterator(this);
        //return iterator;
        return new Iterator(this);
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach(T item in this)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
```

The getEnumerator method should connect the iterator class and the vector class
The iterator class has follow methods

1. Current()
2. MoveNext()
3. Reset()
   and an Iterator constructor

   private Vector _vector;
   public Iterator(Vector vector)
   {
   _vector = vector;
   }

Comment: You didn't really ask a question

Comment: The two GetEnumrator methods are not correct, What should be inside them?

Comment: We need more information. How should an instance of your class behave when it is enumerated?

Comment: I'd say it's more typical for GetEnumerator to just call on GetEnumerator<T>, and it's the <T> version that returns something that does the work

Comment: Typical problem of c++ developer starting with c#. Just use List (IList) instead. Ultimate goal of every developer should be to keep the code clean and simple as possible. And it will get complex and dirty when it grows big by default.